# SQL - Selecting countries with highest count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hello and thanks in advance!

I want to query the 5 **countries** with the highest percentage of their check-ins being at 'Starbucks'.
Below is the example of the table I am working with and has many more rows not shown

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/PzjmeVGnJwmOpAzmTmWbMM6v_8D-2otgiytXE8hfdxzHb3WnvhknQYmQBCYf3P6AOtOURnZq7-gsFegaaSDFN41LN0JLItN9OGvW9qSiVd-h59xEJej-EITqF7DJu2s3ig=w730

I can query counts of all check-ins in a specific country and counts of starbucks check-ins in a specific country separately.

all check-ins query

```
select loc_ctry, count(loc_ctry)
from Table_T
group by loc_ctry
```

starbucks check-ins query

```
select loc_ctry, count(loc_ctry)
from Table_T
where loc_name = 'Starbucks'
group by loc_ctry
```

However, I am having a hard time querying both at the same time to calculate the percentage.
Any help will be appreciated!

EDITS: Thanks everyone for helping out. I have figured out the correct query as below:

```
SELECT   TOP 5 loc_ctry, cast((COUNT(CASE loc_name WHEN 'Starbucks' THEN 1 END)) as decimal) / count(*) as percents
FROM     Table_T
GROUP BY loc_ctry
ORDER BY percents DESC
```

Comment: If the correct query was ran against the example table, the result will show US on top of the list with 50% since there are 4 total check-ins with 2 being at Starbucks

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Case col_name when value then 1 - is so cool. It takes 0 for else cases? Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression inside the `count` to count the StarBucks check-ins and divide it by the total check-ins:

```sql
SELECT   TOP 5 loc_ctry, COUNT(CASE loc_name WHEN 'Starbucks' THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*)
FROM     table_t
GROUP BY loc_ctry
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you input! I modified your query a little bit with cast function on the counts and it is working as expected

Comment: @AlH oh, good catch on the casting! Without it, you'll get an integer division

Answer (score 1):

If you want find out top 5 `Starbucks` percentage try below query. And also you have 6 entries in `image` link and 2 for starbucks. Percentage should be `33.33`. Count was `cast to decimal` for getting percentage calculation.

```
select top 5 * from 
(
select loc_ctry, ((TotalCountCountry/TotalCount)*100) Percentage from
(
 select loc_ctry, cast(count(loc_ctry) as decimal(18,2)) TotalCountCountry
,cast((select Count(*) from Table_T) as decimal(18,2)) TotalCount
from Table_T
where loc_name = 'Starbucks'
group by loc_ctry
) a
) b order by Percentage desc
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! Your recommendation to cast the count to decimal was the last piece I needed for the correct query.

Comment: but what about the other countries that have no starbucks

Comment: op only asked for `Starbucks` .

Answer (score 0):

This is my first post here hope it will help you!

**1st** method: Universal:

```
SELECT TOP 5 loc_ctry, COUNT(*) * 100.0 / (SELECT count(*) FROM Table_T)
FROM Table_T
WHERE loc_name = 'Starbucks'
GROUP BY loc_ctry
```

**2nd** method: Using `Over()`:

```
SELECT TOP loc_ctry, COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER()
FROM Table_T
WHERE loc_name = 'Starbucks'
GROUP BY loc_ctry
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `avg()` to calculate the ratio and then just select the number you want:

```
select top (5) loc_ctry,
       avg(case when loc_name = 'Starbucks' then 1.0 else 0 end) as starbucks_ratio
from Table_T
group by loc_ctry
order by starbucks_ratio desc;
```